# How to declare functions in Swift?

Tags: swiftui

I want to know how to declare and call functions using SwiftUI, I have written the following code, what is wrong with it?

```
  struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        printHello()
    }
    
    func printHello() {
        print("Hello from function!")
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s doesn’t seem to be any wrong. What trouble are you having?

Comment: @rlong405 in SwiftUI you can't have functions inside the `var body`

Comment: Ah sorry. Long day. I checked that the function wasn’t in the body but completely overlooked the fact that it was attempting to be called from within the body. Oops :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside `var body: some View { ... }` must be a `View`. Your function `printHello()` is not a `View`, so it doesn't work.

You're probably looking for the [`onAppear` modifier](https://swiftontap.com/view/onappear(perform:)), which is called when a `View` appears.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This Text is a View")
            .onAppear { /// called when the Text (a View) appears
                printHello()
            }
    }
    
    func printHello() {
        print("Hello from function!")
    }
}
```